# Unexpected result using OR operator in regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I've a problem with a regular expression. I have a text which is read from a file. The text can contain one or more IDs separated by comma.
And then I have a list of IDs and want to check if one of these IDs match with my text so I try to use an OR operator:

```
$idString = '2561,3,261,6,540,33,3105,2085,38,42,1066,49,3377,53,3161,91,356,3179,3695,3184,370,123,3451,124,3710,2188,141,404,1435,160,1443,432,435,440,1721,3261,2498,205,3282,476,482,3301,486,749,3309,243,3059,759,2046,4,262,785,534,541,3360,34,3106,2086,39,43,50,3378,54,1337,61,1351,3157,3162,360,3696,3185,631,3450,3200,666,1436,673,1444,3748,3262,2499,206,3279,3283,470,477,483,3302,490,755,760,2047,2562,1029,263,23,542,35,3107,2087,40,552,553,1321,47,51,3379,55,1338,3163,361,3697,3186,633,3452,639,143,3223,1445,3749,1450,3263,2500,207,3284,478,484,3303,2559,264,1297,22,543,36,44,57,1339,3389,62,3164,3677,362,3180,634,144,1685,1446,430,700,208,3286,479,1249,485,3306,2558,255,265,524,30,288,46,2095,63,2375,3165,403,1447,3242,696,1724,3557,3304,1770,3066,2563,266,544,2338,555,3131,3166,2204,415,1448,1239,3288,480,3305,754,267,545,3370,2378,3152,3170,648,147,679,1449,2537,753,2546,505,2564,3335,268,535,537,539,546,549,65,69,3167,148,3244,744,3068,2565,269,286,547,292,1334,1340,3659,3168,383,153,1705,3267,3060,2566,270,271,3099,548,1660,398,154,1706,2511,746,3332,2568,272,3148,422,3269,752,768,273,3381,3153,3199,155,468,784,274,3093,325,1657,3319,510,3329,3333,275,1432,2230,441,1722,773,3338,276,3641,2108,491,3339,277,2398,107,3181,2245,757,3346,2100,619,1760,2050,3351,2103,667,19,3372,2534,1064,351,1726,2394,2508,2538,2104,3147,2083,2097,2042,2096,2165,2049,2525,2526,1774,2392,2080,2043,2542,2547,2129,2540,2536,2190,2226,2569,2572,2373,2507';
$idString = str_replace(',', '|', $idString);
$text = '1453,2018';
if (preg_match('/' . $idString . '/', $text)) {
  echo 'yes' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
  echo 'no' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I'm expecting that nothing matches because the IDs 1453 and 2018 are not found in my lookup string but it matches. I think that's because the ID 3 matches with 1453 but this is not correct for my use case.

Comment: First off you need to do `'/\b(' . $idString . ')\b/'`, secondly I think working with arrays is much better.

Comment: This seems like it might be easier if you just converted both strings to arrays, and looked at the [`intersection`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: You don't need `regex` for such a simple task. `array_intersect(explode(',', $idString), explode(',', $text))` is enough to get the list of IDs that are present in both strings. If you already have the IDs as numbers in an array then you don't even need to explode `$idStrings` (i.e. code that is faster and easier to read and understand).

Comment: Sorry, what I've forgot to say is that it's an example to reproduce the problem. Later I want to use the regex for elasticsearch. So it's strongly necessary to solve it by a regx.

Comment: For the explanation, you have id `53` in your regexp, so as 53 is contained by your text `1453,2018`it matches. Whatever, using arrays would be more effective

Comment: The reason is clear but I want that only the whole numbers match.

Comment: You got your answer in first comment then. I posted as a separate answer for more details below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's too easy to work around it using arrays. You shouldn't use Regular Expressions if you can work with them but it seems this is not your real problem but an MCVE for a different one.

You should use word boundaries `\b` otherwise a number like `4` is found in `1453`. `preg_match()` third argument holds results to analyze what is going on.

```
preg_match('/\b(?:' . $idString . ')\b/', $text, $match)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see what gets matched by your Regex by outputting the matches, eg:

```
if (preg_match('/' . $idString . '/', $text, $matches)) {
    echo 'yes' . PHP_EOL;
    print_r($matches);
} else {
    echo 'no' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

You'd have to adapt your regex to match against whole words only... for example like this:

```
if (preg_match('/\b(' . $idString . ')\b/', $text)) {
```

https://regex101.com/r/M1Pieb/2/

Or you could avoid using regex altogether (recommended, its getting a bit crazy..) by using explode

```
$idString = '2561,3,261,6,540,33,3105,2085,38,42,1066,49,3377,53,3161,91,356,3179,3695,3184,370,123,3451,124,3710,2188,141,404,1435,160,1443,432,435,440,1721,3261,2498,205,3282,476,482,3301,486,749,3309,243,3059,759,2046,4,262,785,534,541,3360,34,3106,2086,39,43,50,3378,54,1337,61,1351,3157,3162,360,3696,3185,631,3450,3200,666,1436,673,1444,3748,3262,2499,206,3279,3283,470,477,483,3302,490,755,760,2047,2562,1029,263,23,542,35,3107,2087,40,552,553,1321,47,51,3379,55,1338,3163,361,3697,3186,633,3452,639,143,3223,1445,3749,1450,3263,2500,207,3284,478,484,3303,2559,264,1297,22,543,36,44,57,1339,3389,62,3164,3677,362,3180,634,144,1685,1446,430,700,208,3286,479,1249,485,3306,2558,255,265,524,30,288,46,2095,63,2375,3165,403,1447,3242,696,1724,3557,3304,1770,3066,2563,266,544,2338,555,3131,3166,2204,415,1448,1239,3288,480,3305,754,267,545,3370,2378,3152,3170,648,147,679,1449,2537,753,2546,505,2564,3335,268,535,537,539,546,549,65,69,3167,148,3244,744,3068,2565,269,286,547,292,1334,1340,3659,3168,383,153,1705,3267,3060,2566,270,271,3099,548,1660,398,154,1706,2511,746,3332,2568,272,3148,422,3269,752,768,273,3381,3153,3199,155,468,784,274,3093,325,1657,3319,510,3329,3333,275,1432,2230,441,1722,773,3338,276,3641,2108,491,3339,277,2398,107,3181,2245,757,3346,2100,619,1760,2050,3351,2103,667,19,3372,2534,1064,351,1726,2394,2508,2538,2104,3147,2083,2097,2042,2096,2165,2049,2525,2526,1774,2392,2080,2043,2542,2547,2129,2540,2536,2190,2226,2569,2572,2373,2507';
$idStrings = explode(',', $idString);
$values = ['1453', '2018'];

$matchedValue = null;
foreach ($values as $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $idStrings)) {
        $matchedValue = $value;
        break;
    }
}

if ($matchedValue !== null) {
    echo 'yes: ' . $matchedValue;
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `preg_match` is `($pattern, $text)`. Change it as follows, worked for me.

```
<?php

$idString = '2561,3,261,6,540,33,3105,2085,38,42,1066,49,3377,53,3161,91,356,3179,3695,3184,370,123,3451,124,3710,2188,141,404,1435,160,1443,432,435,440,1721,3261,2498,205,3282,476,482,3301,486,749,3309,243,3059,759,2046,4,262,785,534,541,3360,34,3106,2086,39,43,50,3378,54,1337,61,1351,3157,3162,360,3696,3185,631,3450,3200,666,1436,673,1444,3748,3262,2499,206,3279,3283,470,477,483,3302,490,755,760,2047,2562,1029,263,23,542,35,3107,2087,40,552,553,1321,47,51,3379,55,1338,3163,361,3697,3186,633,3452,639,143,3223,1445,3749,1450,3263,2500,207,3284,478,484,3303,2559,264,1297,22,543,36,44,57,1339,3389,62,3164,3677,362,3180,634,144,1685,1446,430,700,208,3286,479,1249,485,3306,2558,255,265,524,30,288,46,2095,63,2375,3165,403,1447,3242,696,1724,3557,3304,1770,3066,2563,266,544,2338,555,3131,3166,2204,415,1448,1239,3288,480,3305,754,267,545,3370,2378,3152,3170,648,147,679,1449,2537,753,2546,505,2564,3335,268,535,537,539,546,549,65,69,3167,148,3244,744,3068,2565,269,286,547,292,1334,1340,3659,3168,383,153,1705,3267,3060,2566,270,271,3099,548,1660,398,154,1706,2511,746,3332,2568,272,3148,422,3269,752,768,273,3381,3153,3199,155,468,784,274,3093,325,1657,3319,510,3329,3333,275,1432,2230,441,1722,773,3338,276,3641,2108,491,3339,277,2398,107,3181,2245,757,3346,2100,619,1760,2050,3351,2103,667,19,3372,2534,1064,351,1726,2394,2508,2538,2104,3147,2083,2097,2042,2096,2165,2049,2525,2526,1774,2392,2080,2043,2542,2547,2129,2540,2536,2190,2226,2569,2572,2373,2507';
$idString = str_replace(',', '|', $idString);
$text = '1453,2018';
if (preg_match('/(' . $text . ')/', $idString)) {
  echo 'yes' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
  echo 'no' . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```